# Securing routes with sessionStorage in NextJS

Tags: javascript, session, next.js

I'm trying to secure a page using a jwt token in a session in NextJS, I was looking at similar questions on the forum and I saw that they recommended using useeffect to get access but I still can't recover anything.

The code I started with:

```
"use client";

import {
    useEffect,
    useState
} from "react";
import {
    useRouter
} from 'next/navigation'
import {
    valJwt
} from "@/libs/jwtSec";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default function isAuth(Component: any) {
    return function IsAuth(props: any) {

        const auth = valJwt(sessionStorage.getItem("token_test"));

        useEffect(() => {
            if (!auth) {
                return redirect("/");
            }
        }, []);


        if (!auth) {
            return null;
        }

        return < Component {
            ...props
        }
        />;
    };
}
```

Output:

```
ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
```

And the edition with which I do not recover anything is this:

```
"use client";

import {
    useEffect,
    useState
} from "react";
import {
    useRouter
} from 'next/navigation'
import {
    valJwt
} from "@/libs/jwtSec";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default function isAuth(Component: any) {
    return function IsAuth(props: any) {

        const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

        useEffect(() => {
            let tok_ses = sessionStorage.getItem("token_test");
            if (tok_ses) {
                setToken(tok_ses);
            }
        }, []);

        useEffect(() => {
            if (token) {
                const auth = valJwt(sessionStorage.getItem("token_test"));
                if (!auth) {
                    return redirect("/");
                }
            }
        }, [token]);

    };
}
```

I tried with `js-cookie` but I can't get access from the same function either, how could I get access?

I need to access the content of a `sessionStorage` from NextJS on the client side.

Comment: The error of the first code makes sense as it runs on the server and sessionStorage and other browser-APIs are not accessible on the server. That's why it says it's not defined. the 2nd solution should work but you should return your component. TIP: you don't need to use HOC when you are dealing with function components. just make a custom hook: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sessionStorage` is a browser API that is not available in the server-side rendering (SSR) environment of Next.js. This is why you're getting the `ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined` error.

To access the `sessionStorage` in Next.js, you need to use the useEffect hook and check if `window` and `window.sessionStorage` are available before attempting to access `sessionStorage`

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { valJwt } from "@/libs/jwtSec";

export default function isAuth(Component: any) {
  return function IsAuth(props: any) {
    const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        const tok_ses = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token_test");
        if (tok_ses) {
          setToken(tok_ses);
        }
      }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (token) {
        const auth = valJwt(token);
        if (!auth) {
          router.push("/");
        }
      }
    }, [token, router]);

    if (!token) {
      return null;
    }

    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
}
```